# Upgrading framework on a ASP.Net MVC Solution

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, upgrade

We have an ASP.Net MVC 1.0 solution developed using Visual Studio 2008 and .net Framework 3.5SP1.

We would now like to upgrade Visual Studio to 2010.

1. If we just open the solution in VS 2010 and do not change the framework version, can we just continue to develop as before?
2. If we open the solution in VS 2010 and change the framework version to 4.0, will we automatically start using ASP.Net MVC 2.0, or will it continue to use ASP.Net MVC 1.0?
3. Is there anything we need to take into consideration when upgrading to ASP.Net MVC 2.0?

Thanks

Shiraz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes.
2. I don't know if this is supported, but I wouldn't go there. It would make more sense to update to MVC 2 first, *then* .NET 4.
3. Yes, lots. Look at the release notes on CodePlex. Many things have changed, including model binding, `TempData` handling, and the return types of HTML helpers. These are breaking changes. There's [a wizard](http://blogs.msdn.com/webdevtools/archive/2010/04/13/visual-studio-2010-mvc-2-upgrade-wizard.aspx) which tries to help, but you're going to have to fix some of this manually.

Answer (score 0):

It will continue using ASP.NET 1.0 unless you run the tool to upgrade to 2.0.  If I am not mistaken, all the tool does is update your web.config to point all MVC references to 2.0 instead of 1.0